# Copying Information based on conditions in an Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of open invoices listed in Excel per office.  How can I use a macro to split these open invoices per office into different Excel sheets, and then save each sheet as the office number? Below is a sample list where the first column is the office number, the entire line associated would have to be copied over to the new sheet.

```
1   180 JOHN    30073   COMPANY X   15,101  173,758 255,713 8/1/2011    8,101   8/24/11 Adair has approved the rates!
1   278 ADAM    159334  COMPANY A   28,606  116,174 158,925 5/9/2011    167,631 7/18/11 Julie Levinsohn still needs to look at reduced entries to see if we can resubmit.
2   600 ROSE    113724  COMPANY 123 0   5,918   20,446  8/22/2011   6,713   8/26/11 Em M Belcher Jul invs per her request. 
2   289 SUE 149232  COMPANY BC  389 5,575   12,098  4/22/2011   328 8/23/11 Em w/jun inv to R. Kos 
2   169 MIKE    120126  COMPANY 98  41,907  5,218   202,756 8/18/2011   33,635  8/24/11 Jun invs to be pd mid sept per Patrice.
2   849 BOB 63068   COMPANY CB  2,862   4,889   9,271   4/25/2011   4,279   8/23/11 Called Choi re when and how much she will send. 
2   849 LANEY   170318  COMPANY 34  0   4,123   6,283   6/30/2011   270 8/17/11 Robert em me re working w/cj re problem w/retainer hrs and bills.
2   707 BOB 153213  COMPANY CI  0   3,127   3,127   5/6/2011    257 4/27/11 Appeals for some of the shortpays by insurance co are pending per 
2   141 SUE 65267   COMPANY Z   9,652   2,313   12,546  7/20/2011   8,380   8/16/11 Stmt em to Pat for pmt of os invs. 
2   705 MIKE    173993  COMPANY X   5,020   2,240   7,294   7/19/2011   1,120   8/24/11 Pmt is processing. 
2   763 JOHN    85919   COMPANY LK  3,500   0   4,500   8/22/2011   1,014   8/19/11 Inv 5637061 in a/p for pmt per cl.
2   400 MIKE    41218   COMPANY 90  3,433   0   3,433   8/24/2011   2,270   5/27/09 Per Hall, ck has been signed and mailed for Feb inv. 
3   164 MIKE    133625  COMPANY LO  500 19,351  21,795  7/25/2011   636 8/16/11 Em to B. Kampas re my calling for pmt
3   178 BOB 168512  COMPANY GH  889 15,749  17,030  6/9/2011    2,322   8/24/11 L/m for M Cornejo to call re osbal due.
3   1005    SUE     164680  COMPANY TH  0   13,862  14,459  8/24/2010   5,000   07/06/11 snt ar statement.dtelles 
3   164 LANEY   61383   COMPANY RT  0   11,077  65,316  7/29/2011   31,750  8/30/11 Inv 5567542 being revised per 
3   171 SUE 78029   COMPANY 345 0   10,507  20,385  8/15/2011   10,165  8/26/11 May invs em to susan
3   164 JOHN    62161   COMPANY 383 14,000  10,500  73,376  8/22/2011   3,500   8/26/11 Invs 5655722 and 5629996 are flat fee bills
3   1139    MIKE    169932  COMPANY 282 145 10,401  10,546  8/24/2011   800 8/26/11 $800 recd. 
3   171 CHRIS   134278  COMPANY 202 0   9,603   9,603   8/15/2011   38,300  8/11/11 JP em from Myriam that ck cut today
3   1363    CHRIS   166031  COMPANY CW  0   8,987   8,987   9/17/2010   4,104   8/3/11 em to Brad K about speaking to Charles 
3   171 JOHN    139383  COMPANY WE  3,872   8,712   23,575  8/19/2011   5,608   07/06/11 snt ar stmnt.
3   198 MIKE    118294  COMPANY LC  0   3,262   3,262   3/9/2011    1,000   8/15/11 Em Cl for a $500 pmt.
3   1139    BOB 176647  COMPANY XC  0   2,673   11,648  7/26/2011   12,152  8/24/11 Em w/may inv sent to  for pmt. 
3   1223    BOB 163879  COMPANY NC  4,550   185 4,735   8/15/2011   32,815  8/4/11 Mar, Apr May invs revised and sent to Cl 
3   1139    BOB 169094  COMPANY 321 5,000   173 12,728  7/20/2011   4,730   8/30/11 CP em Gayle W9 and inv 5625894
3   178 SUE 5416    COMPANY DW  2,670   0   9,596   8/8/2011    2,496   8/24/11 Sent stmt to V. Wu.
3   762 CHRIS   112507  COMPANY IC  6,000   0   12,293  8/8/2011    4,013   07/06/11 snt ar stmnt.
3   631 JOHH    108718  COMPANY IF  15,842  0   43,215  8/26/2011   5,515   07/06/11 snt ar stmnt
4   133 LANEY   157042  COMPANY IR  0   92,879  114,157 5/6/2011    116,483 08/18/2011,jw, emailed Carolyn
4   502 LANEY   66422   COMPANY IG  30,291  58,792  160,301 8/23/2011   24,512  9/17/10 JP sent f/u em to Robin re past due inv
4   155 CHRIS   72564   COMPANY 853 3,283   55,918  62,367  8/4/2011    500 10/19/05 lg recd call from karen,invs will be pd as of next week
4   500 BOB 128230  COMPANY URE 850 49,217  51,006  12/3/2010   2,353   06/29/2011,jw, asked Dk for collection ypdate 
4   751 MIKE    174393  COMPANY KRIG    0   42,753  60,057  7/5/2011    3,658       
4   1384    JOHN    143392  COMPANY IR  0   42,468  42,468  10/27/2010  -2,500  7/20/11 Account turned over to collections.
4   1135    MIKE    169399  COMPANY IGD 1,517   38,857  44,108  7/3/2011    1,539   07/07/2011,jw, emailed Jake for collecti on update   
4   1135    CHRIS   151511  COMPANY IGDS    608 37,458  42,010  7/29/2011   5,691   07/07/2011,jw, emailed Jake for collection update
5   101 BOB 140464  COMPANY IDGS    0   9,226   16,185  7/20/2011   1,120   10/13/10 JP call from Sun req copy of os inv be em
5   281 JOHN    155780  COMPANY IERE    0   9,214   14,557  8/22/2011   13,097  5/3/11Inv 5440713 to clnt mi   
5   288 JOHN    86325   COMPANY 832 1,140   9,178   11,458  8/22/2011   2,824   12/10/09 am received em advising they r moving
```

Comment: Based on the info provided I would not do this.  Why do you want each company on a separate sheet?  I would leave the raw data as is and have one presentation sheet which manipulates the raw data to display the required company info.  You made need to advanced filter (by company) the required invoices to a second raw data sheet and then use formulas etc to extract the data from this sheet onto your presentation sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this; it should work, assuming the office number is column A and there are row headings:

```
Dim Source As Range
Dim OfficeNumber As String
Dim PrevOfficeNumber As String
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Set Source = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Row = 1 To Source.Rows.Count
    OfficeNumber = CurrentSheet.Cells(Row, 1)
    If OfficeNumber <> PrevOfficeNumber Then
        ' create a new sheet
        newrow = 1
        Set NewSheet = Application.Sheets.Add
        NewSheet.Name = OfficeNumber
        PrevOfficeNumber = OfficeNumber
    End If

    ' copy row to new sheet
    CurrentSheet.Cells(Row, 1).EntireRow.Copy (NewSheet.Cells(newrow, 1))
    newrow = newrow + 1
Next
```